# Perl HTML::TableExtract- can't find headers

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm having a little trouble getting the HTML:TableExtract module in perl working. The problem (I think), is that the table headers contain html code to produce subscripts and special symbols, so I'm not sure how this should be searched for using the headers method. I've tried using the full headers (with tags), and also just the text, neither of which work. I'm trying to extract the tables from the following page (and similar ones for other isotopes):

http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat2/getdataset.jsp?nucleus=208PB&unc=nds

Since I've had no luck with the headers method, I've also tried just specifying the depth and count in the object constructor (presumably both = 0 since there is only one top level table on the page), but it still doesn't find anything. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my attempt using the headers method:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w



use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TableExtract;



my $numArgs = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($numArgs != 1) {
    print "Usage: perl convertlevels.pl  <HTML levels file>\n";
    exit;
}

my $htmlfile = $ARGV[0];
open(INFILE,$htmlfile) or die();

my $OutFileName;

if($htmlfile =~ /getdataset.jsp\?nucleus\=(\d+\w+)/){

    $htmlfile =~ /getdataset.jsp\?nucleus\=(\d+\w+)/;

    $OutFileName = "/home/dominic/run19062013/src/levels/".$1.".lev";

}

my $htmllines = <INFILE>;

open(OUTFILE,">",$OutFileName) or die();


my $te = new HTML::TableExtract->new(headers => ['E<sub>level</sub> <br> (keV)','XREF','J&pi;','T<sub>1/2</sub>'] );

$te->parse_file($htmllines);

if ($te->tables)
{
      print "I found a table!";
}else{

    print "No tables found :'(";

}


close INFILE;

close OUTFILE;
```

Please ignore for now what is going on with the OUTFILE- the intention is to reformat the table contents and print into a separate file that can be easily read by another application. The trouble I am having is that the table extract method cannot find any tables, so when I test to see if anything found, the result is always false! I've also tried some of the other options in the constructor of the table extract object, but same story for every attempt! First time user so please excuse my n00bishness.

Thanks!

Comment: You are using two times new here `my $te = new HTML::TableExtract->new(headers => ['E<sub>level</sub> <br> (keV)','XREF','J&pi;','T<sub>1/2</sub>'] );` change it to `my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new(headers => ['E<sub>level</sub> <br> (keV)','XREF','J&pi;','T<sub>1/2</sub>'] );`

Comment: Thanks Arunesh. I've sorted this out now- was also a problem that I wasn't feeding the whole input file into a single string (which I ended up doing using File::Slurp), so the HTML::TableExtract could never find anything.

Comment: Self answers are welcome